# Index out of Range error keeps hapening when I use Pool.starmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When I try to use `pool.starmap` with multiple args, It results in an error.

```py
...

def snake_process(x, snakes, snake, nets, max_score, ge):
    print("start process no" + str(x))
    while True:
        state_old, dis_old = agent.get_state(snake)
        output = nets[x].activate(state_old)
        final_move = [0, 0, 0]
        final_move[np.argmax(output)] = 1
        reward, done, score = snake.play_step(final_move)
        if score > max_score:
            max_score = score
        ge[x].fitness = reward
        if done:
            snake.reset()
            snakes.pop(x)
            nets.pop(x)
            ge.pop(x)
            break
...

def main(genomes, config):
    nets =[]
    ge = []
    snakes = []

    max_score = 0

    for _, g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        snakes.append(Snake(BLOCK_WIDTH*BLOCKS, BLOCK_WIDTH*BLOCKS))
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g)

    num_cores = mp.cpu_count()

    with mp.Pool(num_cores) as pool:
        args = [(x, snakes, snake, nets, max_score, ge) for x, snake in enumerate(snakes)]
        pool.starmap(snake_process, args)
...
def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)
    p = neat.Population(config)
    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stat = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stat)

    winner = p.run(main, GENS)
    print('\nBest genome:\n{!s}'.format(winner))

    visualize.draw_net(config, winner, False)
    visualize.plot_stats(stat, ylog=False, view=False)

    with open("winner.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(winner, f)
        f.close()
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config-feedforward.txt')
    if REPLAY_FILE:
        replay_genome(config_path)
    elif SEE_PROGRESS:
        run_with_progress(config_path)
    else:
        run(config_path)
```

I'm trying to multiprocess `snake_process` function in the code above, but "List Index out of range" error keeps happening.

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a stack trace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.